# Is the National Assembly elected?

Tags: politics, government, skyward

In *Skyward*, there is a National Assembly on Detritus. It is a congress/parliament of some sort. However, FM says that Detritus has a “military government” and is an autocracy controlled by the DDF.

If that is true, is the National Assembly an independent legislature, elected by citizens, or is it just a branch of the autocratic, DDF-controlled government?

Comment: It appears to be comprised of the great and the good; "*“Son of the Jeshua Weight, a hero of the Battle of Alta. She flew seven years in the DDF, and has over a hundred confirmed kills. Her husband is Algernon Weight, National Assembly Leader and high foreman of our largest intercavern shipping company. They’re among the most heavily merited people in the lower caverns.”*". There's no indication that I can see of anything involving voting or democracy or elections.

Comment: I got the impression it was not elected - that it was in fact a mix of old war heroes and well-connected movers that used their reputation to protect their own - they were abandoning the base and stealing all their children back from the military, were they not?

Comment: I thought I was on Politics for a second when I saw this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My impression is that the noblemen - The First Citizens - rule the state. The head of each family seems to make up the National Assembly. There's a passage late in the book where the Admiral of the DDF has to answer to the National Assembly members (although the Admiral herself is a First Citizen too):

Part 5, interlude:

> There was *three* National Assembly Leaders. Normally, they sent underlings to these post-battle briefings, but Judy had been expecting a larger confrontation for some time. She would need something to give them.
>   ...
>   "During your tenure," Ukrit added, "our reserve of ships has fallen to historic lows."

(Ukrit being one of the National Assembly Leaders).

Tenure suggests that the position of Admiral is temporary, based on competence and experience more than anything else. She is not the ruler of the nation.

Social class is heavily based on merits, pilots holding higher standing than others. It seems very important for the noble/rich families that their children have been accepted as Cadets and Pilots.

So it would be a mix of Oligarchy/Meritocracy. There's no mentioning of elections of any kind. Perhaps no wonder given the constant national emergency.